# How to create a new workbook from a sheet with InputBox for its name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets. One is template, another one is a list. I managed to build a code to auto-populate the list based on data from the template using an offset function. The last bit of the script contains an error. What I wanted to achieve was to create a new workbook from the template and save under a name you can type in a window, hence InputBox function.

Just for reference the template is "NCR ACTION RECORD"
                   the list is "Data"

```
Sub Macro()

Dim strNCRReference As String, strType As String
Dim strOpenDate As String, strSupplierName As String
Dim strPartNo As String, Qty As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbName As String


Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate

strNCRReference = Range("A4")
strType = Range("B4")
strOpenDate = Range("C4")
strSupplierName = Range("F4")
strPartNo = Range("G4")
Qty = Range("H4")

Worksheets("Data").Activate
Range("A1").Activate

Do

  If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Loop

ActiveCell.Value = strNCRReference
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = strType
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = strOpenDate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = strSupplierName
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = strPartNo
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = Qty

Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate
  Set wb = Workbook.Add
ThisWorkbook.Activate

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.Activate
wbName = InputBox("Enter a name of a new sheet")
wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\wbName.xlsx"

End Sub
```

The error is Run-time error '424'
Object required.

Comment: change this: `wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\wbName.xlsx"` to this: `wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\" & wbName & ".xlsx"`. `wbName` is a variable, VBA will read anything between `""` as a String. thought it wouldn't give you an error... where exactly in the code is giving you the error?

Comment: Add an ```Option Explicit``` at the beginning of each module/userform : it will prevent your project of compiling in case of typo mistake

Comment: Here is the error : _Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate_ It says _Subscript out of range_.

Comment: @SamuelBalun what does `ThisWorkbook.Open` ? does it open the good file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did some typo in your code :

1 : `Workbooks.Add` and not `Workbook.Add`

2 : `wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\" & wbName & ".xlsx"` and not `wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\wbName.xlsx"`

So your code would be like that

```
Sub Macro()

    Dim strNCRReference As String, strType As String
    Dim strOpenDate As String, strSupplierName As String
    Dim strPartNo As String, Qty As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wbName As String


    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "NCR ACTION RECORD" Then Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate


    strNCRReference = Range("A4")
    strType = Range("B4")
    strOpenDate = Range("C4")
    strSupplierName = Range("F4")
    strPartNo = Range("G4")
    Qty = Range("H4")

    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate

    Do

      If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

    Loop

    ActiveCell.Value = strNCRReference
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = strType
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = strOpenDate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = strSupplierName
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = strPartNo
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = Qty

    Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate
      Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.Activate
    wbName = InputBox("Enter a name of a new sheet")
    wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\" & wbName & ".xlsx"
```

End Sub

Comment: your code poped a message Error 9 : Subscript out of range.

Comment: @SamuelBalun It si because you try to activate a sheet already activated do you launch your macro when you are on NCR ACTION RECORD

Comment: @SamuelBalun I edited the code to avoid unnecessary `.Activate` please try again.

Comment: It gets stuck with 7th row  _Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate_ the error is the same _Subscript out of range_

Comment: @SamuelBalun did you put `If ActiveSheet.Name <> "NCR ACTION RECORD" Then Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate` instead of  `Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate` ? This might fix it (see the edit)

Comment: @SamuelBalun The error is still here ? can you try to debug.print ActiveSheet.Name ?

Comment: @SamuelBalun do you have a sheet in your workbook called "NCR ACTION RECORD" ?

Comment: yes the sheet is there. Where do you want me to use debug.print ActiveSheet.Name ?

Comment: write `debug.print ActiveSheet.Name` **before** and **after** `If ActiveSheet.Name <> "NCR ACTION RECORD" Then Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate` 

Tell me what is the value before and after

Comment: It says _NCR ACTION RECORD_ in both cases, so that's good. I separated the code into two parts. The problem  only occures at the last part at creating and copying into a new workbook.

Comment: @SamuelBalun can you please update our issue so I know what are the 2 part ?

Comment: ```Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate
      Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.Activate
    wbName = InputBox("Enter a name of a new sheet")
    wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\S7051895\Desktop\" & wbName & ".xlsx" ```

Comment: can you tell me the line which is highlighted ? Bc this code is working on my computer so i need to define what is the real issue

Comment: It highlights this line _ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)_ . Practically, it's looking for the _NCR ACTION RECORD_ sheet in a wrong workbook.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error @SamuelBalun this is working nicely on my computer. 
make sure that you have 2 Sheet called **NCR ACTION RECORD** and **Data** in the **workbook used to run the macro** ... This must work ..

If this don't work create a **third** sheet go on it and then run your macro .. else tell me how much workbook are opened here and if the macro open correctly the new workbook ...

Comment: @SamuelBalun You can also try to replace `thisworkbook` by `ActiveWorkbook` maybe this would change something

Comment: Ok, I found out the source of my error. I've been trying to run the code from the personal macro module. I wonder why I can't do it from there. However, it's working now. Thank you!

Comment: @SamuelBalun may I ask you to accept my answer, I corrected some stuff in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

It's Workbook**s**.Add, not Workbook.Add. Trying to use the latter in a test-sub on my computer, I get an error "Variable not defined" on the line containing that code, I assume the reason you get a different error is because the workbook-object has not been set when you attempt to interact with it later in the code.

As an additional comment on your code, I would advice you to use

```
With Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD")
    strNCRReference = .Range("A4")
    ...
End With
```

instead of `Worksheets("NCR ACTION RECORD").Activate` and then doing actions on that sheet. The former is much more robust, in addition to being faster code to execute.